# Defining macro to change print function error due to argument difference

Tags: c, putchar, unity-test-framework

I'm trying to use unity testing framework with an NRF51822 board, but in order to see the output from unity i need to reroute it / pipe so its visible on my coumputer. I am using SEGGER RTT to print in my porject and ideally id use the same for unity.c output.

According to unity

> By default, Unity prints its results to `stdout` as it runs. This
>   works perfectly fine in most situations where you are using a native
>   compiler for testing. It works on some simulators as well so long as
>   they have `stdout` routed back to the command line. There are times,
>   however, where the simulator will lack support for dumping results or
>   you will want to route results elsewhere for other reasons. In these
>   cases, you should define the `UNITY_OUTPUT_CHAR` macro. This macro
>   accepts a single character at a time (as an `int`, since this is the
>   parameter type of the standard C `putchar` function most commonly
>   used). You may replace this with whatever function call you like.
>
> ```
> * Output*     - by default, Unity prints to standard out with putchar.  define UNITY_OUTPUT_CHAR(a) with a different function if
> ```
>
> desired

```
   /*-------------------------------------------------------
     * Output Method: stdout (DEFAULT)
     *-------------------------------------------------------*/
    #ifndef UNITY_OUTPUT_CHAR
    /* Default to using putchar, which is defined in stdio.h */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define UNITY_OUTPUT_CHAR(a) (void)putchar(a)
    #else
      /* If defined as something else, make sure we declare it here so it's ready for use */
      #ifndef UNITY_OMIT_OUTPUT_CHAR_HEADER_DECLARATION
    extern void UNITY_OUTPUT_CHAR(int);
      #endif
    #endif
```

I tried to define

```
#define UNITY_OUTPUT_CHAR(a) SEGGER_RTT_WriteString(0, a)
```

However i get the following

```
> $ make rm -rf _build echo  Makefile Makefile mkdir _build Compiling
> file: system_nrf51.c Compiling file: main.c
> C:/NXTSNS/nRF5_SDK_11.0.0_89a8197/examples/peripheral/blinky/main.c:31:53:
> error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before numeric
> constant 
> #define UNITY_OUTPUT_CHAR(a) SEGGER_RTT_WriteString(0, a)
>                                                      ^ C:/NXTSNS/Unittesting/unity/src/unity_internals.h:250:13: note: in
> expansion of macro 'UNITY_OUTPUT_CHAR'  extern void
> UNITY_OUTPUT_CHAR(int);
>              ^ Makefile:150: recipe for target '_build/main.o' failed make: *** [_build/main.o] Error 1
```

I also tried this alternative of calling segger in a function and casting to char *  as follows

```
void print_test(int a){
    SEGGER_RTT_WriteString(0, (char *) a);
}
```

but unfortuneatly i dont see any output when i call print_test

How should i define the macro such that i can send the output to segger or if there is a more suitable alternative what is it?

Comment: When you say Unity, do you mean the game engine? Are you sure this the right tag? This tag is for a game engine framework.

Comment: This doesn't look like Unity3D at all, Unity runs on C# not C and definitely doesn't support these compile directives.

Comment: sorry i meant the testing framework